# Managed switch in 2nd building connected to main switch stack by fiber won't use any VLANs?

Tags: networking

So I have a switch stack and a fiber that comes from it goes to another building on site. On the other end of that fiber is a netgear switch then plugged into it is several desktops and then a Wireless Access Point. I want to Tag the port the Wireless Access point is setup on so my DHCP can start handing out IPs.

I have a Wireless Access Point currently plugged directly into the switch stack for the main building and then in the interface I setup 2 VLANs 5 and 6. Then on my router I setup the VLANs and I am routing them to 2 different IP addresses. My DHCP server on my Windows Server 2008 is handing out IPs just fine in the main building. But I want it to do the same to the building connected to us by fiber. Should I untag the fiber port through the switch stack interface or should I tag it? I want my desktop PCs over in the other building to stay on the main network.

FYI: The VLANS work great in the main building that has the switch stack.

EDIT:

I created 2 wireless networks that use VLAN ID 5 and 6 which is configured on a netgear switch. Barracuda Firewall routes 2 different DHCP scopes from my DHCP server on Windows Server 2008 through the 2 VLANs. When you connect to Wireless Network A which is assigned VLAN ID 5 you get IP address 192.168.2.x and if you connect to Wireless Network B you get IP Address 192.168.3.x.

Currently that works as configured in the main building. The port the WAP is connected to is tagged in VLAN ID 5 and 6. I plugged in another WAP into a managed switch connected by fiber that the VLANs 5 and 6 were configured on originally. The WAP automatically started broadcasting the 2 Wireless Networks but IP addresses aren't being handed out like they are in the main building.

On the managed switch in the 2nd building I have created VLANs 5 and 6 in that switch as well and I tagged the port of the WAP in VLAN 5 and 6 as well as the fiber port that connects the main building.

Comment: Very likely, this is a config error, without seeing the configuration, it's hard to tell. We have to assume.

Comment: You need to make sure that all tagged vlans are passed through the fiber connection between the switches. i.e. the ports on both switches should be "Trunk" (as in the cisco terminology).http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11673/~/how-do-i-setup-a-link-between-two-netgear-switches-to-exchange-multiple-vlan?cid=wmt_netgear_organic

Comment: We expect MUCH more of question askers in terms of details and clarify around your setup and objectives - please add them.

Comment: @bangal I have done that but i am still not being assigned an IP address by DHCP on window server.... But I am assigned an IP in the main building.

Comment: OK, I'm confused. Do you have more than one DHCP server? If devices connected to the WAP that's connected to the downstream switch are getting ip address leases from the correct DHCP scope from the Windows DHCP server then everything **is** working.

Comment: I have only 1 DHCP server but 3 scopes.... scope 1 is the main network and scope 2 is VLAN 5 and scope 3 is VLAN 6

Comment: In your last comment on my answer you said that the WAP is handing out IP addresses.

Comment: WAP has 2 Wireless Networks configured... One network is assigned VLAN 5 and the other WLAN is assigned VLAN 6 if you connect to WLAN with VLAN 5 you get a 192.168.2.x ip and if you connect the other WLAN with VLAN 6 assigned you will then get a 192.168.3.x IP. These IPS are assigned to the device by the DHCP server which has 2 scopes one scope is 192.168.2.x and the other is 192.168.3.x

Answer (score 1):

`I have a Wireless Access Point currently plugged directly into the switch stack for the main building and then in the interface I setup 2 VLANs 5 and 6.`

Interface of what?

`Then on my router I setup the VLANs and I am routing them to 2 different IP addresses.`

What do you mean you're routing them to routing them to two different ip addresses? Do you mean that you're routing between the VLAN's?

`My DHCP server on my Windows Server 2008 is handing out IPs just fine in the main building. But I want it to do the same to the building connected to us by fiber.`

Do you mean that you have a DHCP scope defined for each VLAN and that your DHCP server is successfully handing out ip address leases to machines connected to switch ports in both VLAN's? If so, then you must obviously be using a DHCP relay agent. If you want the DHCP server to do the same for PC's connected to the downstream switch then you need to tag the switch ports that connect the two switches and you need to configure the same VLAN's on the downstream switch as exist on the upstream switch.

`Should I untag the fiber port through the switch stack interface or should I tag it?`

If you want your VLAN's to span both switches then you need to tag the port.

`I want my desktop PCs over in the other building to stay on the main network.`

Do you mean that you want them to be connected to switchports in the same VLAN as the VLAN in the main building? If so, then you need to configure the same VLAN's on the downstream switch as exist on the upstream switch and you need to connect the PC's to switch ports in the correct VLAN.

Comment: Interface of what?: The Switch of the 2nd building

Comment: What do you mean you're routing them to routing them to two different ip addresses? Do you mean that you're routing between the VLAN's?: IP address

Comment: DHCP has a scoped defined for each VLAN..... I recently tagged the fiber port of the main switch and then tag the fiber port of the switch in the 2nd building...... and I want all desktop PCS to stay on the default network while wireless is on the 2 VLANS depending on which wireless network they connect to... this currently works in the main building but not the 2nd building.

Comment: Are the downstream switch ports configured for the correct VLAN membership? Are the WAP's connected to the downstream switch connected to the correct switch ports?

Comment: Yes Port 13 is tagged in VLAN ID 5 and 6 on the managed switch in the 2nd building just like port 23(WAP) is tagged in VLAN ID 5 and 6 of the switch stack in the main building. Both fiber ports are tagged on the main building's switch stack and the managed switch in the 2nd building

Comment: I feel like VLAN 5 and 6 of the switch in the 2nd building isn't connected to the VLAN 5 and 6 to the switch stack in the main building.

Comment: and I feel that way because if i plug another WAP in say port 22 of the main switch stack then tag it in the Netgear switch interface.... the WAP starts handing out IPs depending on what VLAN is being used. Barracuda Firewall is doing the routing to 2 different IP addresses.